# How to get url from linkify textview

Tags: android, youtube, textview, linkify

I need to highlight weburl inside textview. 
To achieve this I have added `android:autoLink="web"` attribute inside my textview xml.

If url is related to youtube video I need to play it inside youtube player activity in my app and for other types of urls i want it to open on web browser. 
So How I detect which url is get click and find is it youtube link or not and perform redirection according to it.

Following are sample text which my text view holding

> this is sample text
>  you can find nice article over this link
>   www.example.com
>  and there is nice video which explain here
>   www.youtube.com/xyzpqr
>  furthere reading please download pdf from
>   here
>  www.example.com/pdf/xyz

there are multiple links is present so need to detect that clicked link and preform action on selected link.

Comment: Are you using YouTubePlayer api to show the YouTube videos in your YouTube Activity?

Comment: I need to play youtube video in side activity Picture in Picture mode using exoplayer

Comment: @dev_swat I do not know how exoplayer handles Youtube videos. Does it need youtube video ID to play the youtube video?

Comment: You should play the Youtube videos inside Google's official YouTubeplayer API if you're planning to build a separate activity for playing youtube videos. https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: @VedprakashWagh youtubevideo link comes in textview and that link is provide to exoplayer to play online content

Comment: Please check my answer. - @dev_swat

Answer (score 0):

You Can Apply Listener on TextView and When Click is Detected use StartsWith Method in Android To Detect if url starts with you.(url of youtube ) if it matches do your youtube player stuff else perform redirection

Answer (score 0):

Please try below attribute in your textview in `xml` file:

```
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        android:textColorLink="#3393FF"
```

You can check URL using contains function.

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String URL = textView.getText().toString();
            if (URL.contains("youtube") || URL.contains("youtu.be")) {
                // then redirect to youtube
            } else if (URL.contains("pdf")) {
                // then redirect to pdf app
            } else {
                // then redirect to web
            }
        }
    });
```

**OR**

you can use below Library and link : https://github.com/saket/Better-Link-Movement-Method

```
implementation 'me.saket:better-link-movement-method:2.2.0'
```

Try below code :

```
BetterLinkMovementMethod
.linkify(Linkify.ALL, textView)
.setOnLinkClickListener((textView, url) -> {
     // Handle clicks.

    if (url.contains("youtube") || url.contains("youtu.be")) {
           // then redirect to youtube
    } else if (url.contains("pdf")) {
           // then redirect to pdf app
    } else {
           // then redirect to web
    }

     return true;
})
.setOnLinkLongClickListener((textView, url) -> {
    // Handle long-clicks.
    return true;
});
```

Comment: I am already added autolink web I only wants to open web urls, but only for youtube link i need to handle inside my custome youtube activity

Comment: how to get selected URL. is there any method on textview like e.g textview.getselectedURL()

Comment: your method check whole textview data and finds youtube and pdf words inside that text, I just url which is highlighted vai linkify text

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `setMouvementMethod()` instead ?

Try this in your TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"/>
```

Then add this line in you Java class:

```
TextView myLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```